# Proving Chromatic number is either X(G) or X(G)-1

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Alright it is  exam season and I need some help studying. I can't get this problem

Let G be a graph and *v* be a vertex in G. Show that the chromatic number X(G-v) is either X(G) or X(G)-1.

Thank you.

Comment: @GerryMyerson its    χ(G)≥χ(G) - 1.................... minus 1

Comment: Sorry, I meant, prove $\chi(G-v)\ge\chi(G)+1$ is impossible, and prove $\chi(G-v)\le\chi(G)-2$ is impossible.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  ok but how do i accomplish that? how do i prove it? I'm stuck on the though process

Comment: You just have to think it through. If you can color $G$ with $n$ colors, what's the greatest number of colors you could possibly need for $G-v$? What's the smallest number of colors you could possibly need for $G-v$? Really, this isn't hard, you just have to think it through.

Comment: In other words, show that $\chi(G)$ is either $\chi(G-v)$ or $\chi(G-v)+1$. That is, if $H$ is a graph then $\chi(H+v)$ is either $\chi(H)+1$ or $\chi(H)$; either you need one more color for the extra vertex, or you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a colouring of $G$ with $\chi(G)$ colours, removing $v$ trivially produces a colouring of $G-v$ with at most $\chi(G)$ colours. Hence $\chi(G-v)\le\chi(G)$.

If $\chi(G-v)\le\chi(G)-2$, then adding the vertex $v$ back produces a colouring of $G$ with at most $\chi(G)-1$ colours ($v$ may need an extra colour), which is a contradiction. Hence $\chi(G-v)\ge\chi(G)-1$.

Combining these two inequalities produces the desired result.